# Using SherlockActionBar library by using its Jar file in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I am using [SHERLOCK-ACTION-BAR](http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html) in my project
I successfully am able to run the project using the library refered in eclipse

**What i am not able to do**::

- I am trying to add `JAR` file to `libs` in my project and run it
  (removing the reference i made earlier to my previous library)
- So i copied the `JAR` from Libs of `Sherlock library` project and added
  to my project
- When i do this i am not able to import the class file from JAR
- Where can i download the correct JAR

Comment: After `JAR` adding you have to clean and built your project.

Comment: @Simple Plan ......Yes I did .... Still it dosen't work .......

Comment: okk then post errors you got.

Comment: @Simple Plan .....  Have a look at this link . https://groups.google.com/d/msg/actionbarsherlock/a9BZ-ugABDA/NuzAan9uLtUJ ............ here JakeWharton says using Jar not possible is it true .... so Sherlocklibrary cannt be used as a jar since it has project with resources ? ... is it 
?

Comment: @c all right let me check it

Answer (score 0):

You can add JAR from Project - Properties.
Then go to Java Build Path and add your JAR or External JAR.

[image]

Clean your project after add it ;)

Comment: Have a look at this link . https://groups.google.com/d/msg/actionbarsherlock/a9BZ-ugABDA/NuzAan9uLtUJ ............ here JakeWharton says using Jar not possible is it true .... so Sherlocklibrary cannt be used as a jar since it has project with resources ? is it ?